# Linking with NS3 module with circular dependency to other library

Tags: c++, static-libraries, circular-dependency, waf, ns-3

I am trying to build custom NS3 module which depends on some static library. This static library depends on NS3 module.

Platform: Ubuntu 16.04 x64
Toolchain: GCC 5.4.0

I will refer to my custom NS3 module as *mymodule*

I will refer to the library which *mymodule* depends on as *mylib*

I will refer to the program which links with *mymodule* and *mylib* as *myprog*

`wscript` for *mymodule*:

```
def build(bld):
   module = bld.create_ns3_module('mymodule', ['network'])
   module.features = 'c cxx cxxstlib ns3module'
   module.source = [
     'model/mymodule.cc' ]

   # Make a dependency to some other static lib:
   bld.env.INCLUDES_MYLIB = [ "some/include/path" ]
   bld.env.LIB_MYLIB = ['mylib']
   bld.env.LIBPATH_MYLIB = [ "some/path" ]
   module.use.append('MYLIB')

   # Create a program which uses mymodule
   p = bld.create_ns3_program('myprog', ['core', 'mymodule'])
   p.source = 'prog.cpp'

   headers = bld(features='ns3header')
   headers.module = 'mymodule'
   headers.source = ['model/mymodule.h']
```

When I do `./waf build` it fails: LD cannot link *myprog* because *mylib* has unresolved symbols. This failure is actually expected because *mylib* and *mymodule* are codependent and should be linked in non-standard way.

Workarounds:

1. If I build *myprog* by hand and use `-Wl,--start-group
   -lns3.26-mymodule-debug -lmylib -Wl,--end-group` it links perfectly fine and works as expected.
2. If I combine two static libs by hand (using `ar -M` script) and then run `./waf build` it also works fine.

**The question:** How can I integrate one of the workarounds above into `wscript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like a known problem with order of static libs inclusion. The behavior has changed in waf 1.9, due to this problem.

One workaround might be to use the `linkflags` attribute of `program`. You should prefer the use of `STLIB_MYLIB` and `STLIBPATH_MYLIB` as mylib is static. In waf 1.9 with he correct order of libs it might suffice.

Anyway, use -v to see the command line generated by waf, it might help !

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately NS3.26 uses waf 1.8.

Comment: Looks like we solved the issue with the following steps: 1) Change `cxxstlib` to `cxxshlib` (..st.. -> ..sh..) it enables `STLIB_*` 2) Put `-fPIC` into module.cflags and mylib makefile 3) Add `STLIB_MYLIB` into wscript